# Inspect element's dimension in Firefox and IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, firebug

In chrome developer tools, I can check the exact dimension for individual element within the browser, but how do you do that in Firefox and IE?

Below is a screenshot of how chrome developer tools capture an element's dimension.

[image: chrome developer tools]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Firefox

Context menu of the element > *Inspect Element*. Or open the developer tools manually and switch to the Inspector. Then on the right you have the *Box Model* tab which shows the element dimensions (and margins, paddings, borders).

[image: Box Model in Firefox DevTools]

Also, Firefox 32+ will display the dimensions in a tooltip-style thingy like Chrome.

#### Internet Explorer

Context menu of the element > *Inspect Element*. Or open the developer tools manually and switch to the *DOM Explorer*. Then on the right you have the *Layout* tab which shows the element dimensions (and offsets, margins, paddings, borders).

[image: Box Model in IE 11 DevTools]

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#layout_tab.